# how to activate encrypt contents to secure data option on a folder

Tags: c#, vb.net, encryption

I have a program in vb in with I need to encrypt the content of a folder, for security issues. I was searching in internet but I don't find a way to to this via vb or c#. Is what I'm looking for is possible? [Advanced Atrributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T6Vj.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a function to activate ntfs encryption on a file or folder:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;


[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool EncryptFile(string filename);

public static void EnableEncryption(string filename)
{
    if (!EncryptFile(filename))
    {
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }
}
```